# How do I know which process carries out the task on the context menu

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu, shell-extensions, file-types

When I right-click on a PNG file, I get a context menu that includes Rotate Clockwise and Rotate Counter Clockwise.  Both work great.

I am trying to figure out what actual EXE or DLL carries out the actual work of rotating images.  Because, I don't think Windows XP includes these out of the box.

I tried going to Tools/Folder Options/File Types tab.  Then scrolling to PNG, but the Advanced button changes to Restore when I click on PNG.

I've tried looking in the registry for keywords "Rotate Clockwise", but no success.
When I actually do the rotation, Explorer.exe CPU usage goes up, which means to me that a DLL of type is doing the work.

How can I find the EXE or the DLL responsible for rotation?

Comment: Not a solution - but for your information - you may need to search for "clockwise" or "rotate" and not the whole word - remember, if there is a shortcut key / underlined letter such as o, it will actually be "r&otate" in the registry (Think it's &, if not it is %)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I know which process carries
>   out the task on the context menu

Very easy: download, unzip and run **[ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)**. the program displays the details of shell extensions installed on your computer, and allows you to easily disable and enable each shell extension.

[image]

> I am trying to figure out what actual
>   EXE or DLL carries out the actual work
>   of rotating images. Because, I don't
>   think Windows XP includes these out of
>   the box.

The extension is called Shell Image Verbs (Windows Picture and Fax Viewer) and the DLL 'responsible for rotation' would be C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll

You won't find the extension in the registry unless you can identify the CLID. ShellExView does that as well, even better: highlight the entry and hit F2; this will open the registry and jump right to the key you're looking for.

*ShellExView is freeware and portable (doesn't require installation).*

Comment: With this application, how did you tie the context menu Rotate Clockwise to the Shell Image Verbs?

Comment: it's the only shell extension related to Windows Picture and Fax Viewer. just turn it off and voilá, Rotate is gone from the context menu ... don't forget to turn it back on :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I believe those are functions of the Windows Picture & Fax Viewer.  In Explorer the options don't appear unless you're browsing image files in Thumbnail view.  I usually browse in Detail view, and those context menu options are not available.  The same context menu items are shown if you open the image in Windows Picture & Fax Viewer and right-click on the image.

Comment: You're right about when the context menu appears - I was in Details View. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the very useful [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) utility, that will report on all auto-startup programs in your computer of any type.

The answer might be found in the Explorer tab of Autoruns.